# How to display multiple contents as marquee one after another? Second content should take some time to display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have two different contents, I want to show the contents as marquee in single line and the contents should display one after another with some delay time duration.

```
<marquee direction="left">
  <label>Label 1 content here</label>
  <label>Label 2 content here</label>
</marquee>
```

Comment: Are you okay with using JavaScript? Marquee tags are long dead.

Comment: yes okay with that.

Comment: Awesome. I am going to add JavaScript and jQuery tags.

Comment: Let me know if my answer helps to an extent at least.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution, without `<marquee>` tag, which is deprecated now:

```js
//list of slides to be shown
const content = [
    'first slide',
    'second slide',
    'third slide'
];

let key = 0;
const marquee = $('.marquee');
marquee.on('animationstart', () => {
    key = 0;
    marquee.text(content[key]);
});
marquee.on('animationiteration', () => {
    key++;
    if(typeof content[key] === 'undefined') key = 0;
    marquee.text(content[key]);
});
marquee.removeClass('paused');
```

```css
.marquee-container {
    width: 100vw;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.marquee {
    padding-left: 100vw;
    display: inline-block;
    animation: marquee 5s linear infinite;
    animation-play-state: running;
}

.marquee.paused, .marquee-container:hover .marquee {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes marquee {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="marquee-container">
    <div class="marquee paused"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `<marquee>` and `<label>` tags (which you shouldn't use in this context), please try using JavaScript this way:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".slider .slide").hide();
  $(".slider .slide:first").fadeIn().delay(10000).fadeOut(function () {
    $(this).next().fadeIn();
  });
  setInterval(function () {
    $(".slider .slide:first").fadeIn().delay(10000).fadeOut(function () {
      $(this).next().fadeIn();
    });
  }, 20000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide"><marquee>Label 1 content here</marquee></div>
  <div class="slide"><marquee>Label 2 content here</marquee></div>
</div>
```

The above is a bare minimal demonstration of what you might like. Let me know if you need more improvement on this. ☺

Comment: Hi @Praveen, I just wanted the content should move from right to left, is it possible using jquery....?

Comment: @Dennis Yep and no. I would use our classic marquee for that. Let me update the answer.

Comment: @Dennis Updated. Check.

Comment: Thank you @Praveen, and the contents should display one after another continuously.....!

Comment: @Dennis Let's put that on a loop! `setInterval()` FTW.

Comment: @Dennis Updated.

Comment: Thank you @Praveen

Comment: No @Praveen, I just wanted to display the contents one by one as moving text in a single line.

Comment: @Dennis Each one should move in a single line?

Comment: yes, one after another with time gap in a single line. Can we make it?

Comment: @Dennis Just adding another marquee tag will work out. Check now.

Comment: Marquee tag is obsolete therefore shouldn't be used.

Comment: @Dennis For some reason it works for me. Alright. Yeah, as I said before, marquee tag isn't reliable.

Answer (score 0):

You may use this way, without marquee, basing on jquery queue and adding a css class to your elements:

```js
$(function () {
var current_button = 0;

$('div.slider .slide:first')
       .show(100)
       .addClass('active');

setInterval(function() {
   if(current_button===$('.slide').length) {
       $('div.slider .slide:first')
       .show(100)
       .addClass('active');
       current_button=0;
   } else {
     $('div.slider .slide')
     .hide(100)
     .removeClass('active');
     
     $('div.slider .slide:eq(' + current_button + ')')
      .show(100)
      .addClass('active');

     current_button++;
   }
},3500)
});
```

```css
.slide {
  float: left;
  transform: translateX(400%);
  transition: all 7s;
}

.active {
  transform: translateX(-350%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">Label 1 content here</div>
  <div class="slide">Label 2 content here</div>
</div>
```

EDIT: I think there is a better way, but I try a solution in the code above.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @ufollettu, can I display the contents continuously ?. Now the content shows only one time.

Comment: @Dennis I try a workaround wiyhout using plugin. is not the better way, but is a way...